# Python DynamoDB create custom last_evaluated_key from particular table entry

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, flash-message, botocore

we need create custom last evaluated key

**The use case goes Here:**

First scan table its having ten records,the tenth record should my last evaluated key when i do second time scan operation

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#Exclusive start key should be null for your first page
esk = None
#Get the first page
scan_generator = MyTable.scan(Limit=10, exclusive_start_key=esk)
#Get the key for the next page
esk = scan_generator.kwargs['exclusive_start_key'].values()
#Now get page 2
scan_generator = MyTable.scan(Limit=10, exclusive_start_key=esk)
```

EDIT:

exclusive_start_key (list or tuple) – Primary key of the item from which to continue an earlier query. This would be provided as the LastEvaluatedKey in that query.

For example

```
exclusive_start_key = ('myhashkey');
```

or

```
exclusive_start_key = ('myhashkey', 'myrangekey');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response,without 'max_results' is not working ??

Comment: Sorry, should have been Limits. [Scan docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.scan)

Comment: Any other way to generate  exclusive start key

Comment: Just create a tuple using the primary key of the item you want to start from.